# Создать отдельные виджеты комментарий

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var id = Number(document.title);
    VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 10, attach: false}, id);
</script>
```

В последней строчке в место ID надо вставлять описание страницы из

```
<meta name="description" content="Интернет зависимость это что то неожиданное " />
```

Чтобы на каждой странице сайта были отдельные комментарий?

Answer (score 0):

Без jquery

```
document.head.querySelector("meta[name=description]").content;
```

С jquery

```
$("meta[name=description]").attr('content');
```

Comment: А можно это полностью А то я не понимаю куда это вставить ?:) Напишите полностью код как будет выглядеть ? Спасибо !

Comment: @Helpsetup, вместо "Number(document.title)"

Comment: Пишет неизвестная ошибка